# React fetch asinchronous data from POST request and display data

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch some data from an API through a POST request, then I would like to display those data on the browser, but I am encountering this problem:

`Line 30:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

My code looks like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";

    class GetData extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        axios
          .post(
            `https://api.multicycles.org/v1?access_token=API_KEY`,
            {
              query:
                "query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {id type attributes lat lng provider { name }}}",
              variables: { lat: 52.229675, lng: 21.01223 }
            }
          )
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
              data: response.data
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
      render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
          <ul className="filter-options">
            {this.state.data.data.map(val => {
              <p>{val.templateFields}</p>;
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      }
    }

    export default GetData;
```

I would like then, to render in `App.js` a component called `<GetData />` and display the results from the API, but I'm still getting the error previously mentioned. 
Where I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function given to `this.state.data.data.map`. You also don't have any default state, so `this.state.data.data` will give rise to an error on first render.

Comment: Does `console.log(response)` actually print a response?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting

```
this.state.data.data
```

from. You're setting

```
this.setState({
    data: response.data
});
```

so I would expect something like

```
this.state.data.map(...)
```

I also don't see a constructor for your component - you need to set default, state, for example

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything in your map try :

```
         <ul className="filter-options">
            {this.state.data.data.map(val => (
              <p>{val.templateFields}</p>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

Also you need a default state in your component.

Comment: Thanks, I set a default state, with empty data, such as `{data: ' '}`, but when I try to return values using your snippet it tells me there is an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token` what am i doing wrong?

Comment: My mistake, you don't need the brackets: try this

<ul className="filter-options">
{this.state.value.map(val => (
  <p>{val.templateFields}</p>
))}
  </ul>

I've edited the initial code with the correct syntax

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix my code in the meanwhile, I was missing to set a state that reflects what I get from the API, then to render it while using `stringify()` to display the whole JSON file. My code was a huge Frankenstein, but thanks to you, guys I managed to understand this first step. Cheers!